# iPhone - deactivate CLLocationManager events when in background mode

Tags: ios, events, background, location, multitasking

I have an app that uses the CLLocationManager to receive location and heading updates. When the app in sent to background mode, the CLLocationManager still receive events (catched in the debugger while the app is not onscreen).

Am I obliged to trap the "sent to background" event and use a BOOL to exit the event delegate method to forget those updates, or stop/restart the CLLocationManager ?

or is there  another solution to stop receiving those events when in background ?

I'd like to prevent this not to do useless actions, and possibly reduce battery, as I don't need those events.

I know there is a project.plist param to set to force iOS to continue sending location events to the app even if it's in background. I didn't set that parameter. So I guess there is a way to tell iOS that I don't want those events when in background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next methods of `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplicetion*)application;
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplicetion*)application;
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplicetion*)application;
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplicetion*)application;
```

Comment: eh eh, ok, but to do what ? Start/stop the location manager ? trap a boolean and filter received calls ? If this is that, I'm talking about it in the question so please, in that case, delete your answer. What I'm searching about is a solution to tell the iOS that when in background, I don't want anymore receive updates. I guess this is possible because there is an app param that force iOS to continue giving updates when the app is in background. So there should be a way to tell i don't want for them.

Comment: You've guessed right, just stop your CLLocationManeger instance from receiving updates in second and third methods and start it again in first and fourth... You can do it with -(void)stopUpdatingLocation; -(void)startUpdatingLocation; methods of CLLocationManager.